# Getting only first entry php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an mysqli table having values as such:-

```
 id | price
  65| 7000
  67| 7001
```

And a php code to echo both out using an array variable:-

```
  require('setup.php'); // got connection
  $array = array(0 => 65, 1 => 67);
  $d = implode("," , $array);
  $sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN('$d')";
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if($query){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
     echo $row['price'].'<br>';
    }
  }
 else {
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
   }
```

The output should come as

```
7000
7001
```

but it's only `7000`.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` => `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Or `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Removed quotes around $q in query It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `IN(65,67)` while you are doing `IN('65,67')`

So remove `'` around `$d`

Code needs to be:-

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)";
```

***Note:-*** use `fetch_assoc()` for lighter array iteration (as it only gives associative array resultset)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

***Working snippet*** :- http://rextester.com/FEFBWZ40805

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra single quotes in `IN()` tag.

Corrected code:

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)";
```

`$sql` Outputs:

`SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN(65,67)`

You can check the code [here](https://3v4l.org/b4VkK):

Answer (score 1):

Passing `$d` withing quotes makes the `IN('65,66')` look like this during execution so you need to remove that as by the default convention you just need to pass an array. So change your query to:

```
SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)
```

Comment: Why?   While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your query as below,

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your SQL query

```
 $sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN('$d')";
```

Please change this query like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)";
```

You should not use single quote with php varible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
require('setup.php'); 
$array = [65, 67];
$d     = implode(',', $array);
$sql   = "SELECT price FROM trade WHERE id IN($d)";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($query){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['price'].'<br>';
    }
}
else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: My array will always be `array(0 => 65, 1 => 67);`